# Adding custom attributes to C# classes using Roslyn

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

Consider the following class in a file "MyClass.cs"

```
using System;

public class MyClass : Entity<long>
{
    public long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Slug
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Currently I manually create data contract classes looking as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/", Name = "MyClass")]
public sealed class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "Id")]
    public long Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "Name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "Slug")]
    public string Slug
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "CreatedOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "UpdatedOn")]
    public DateTime UpdatedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use Roslyn to rewrite "MyClass.cs" so its looks like the class I create by hand. Currently I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(@"..\..\MyClass.cs");
        var source = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(source);
        var rewriter = new MyRewriter();
        var newRoot = rewriter.Visit(tree.Root);
        Console.WriteLine(newRoot.Format());
    }
}

public class MyRewriter : SyntaxRewriter
{
    protected override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var declaration = (TypeDeclarationSyntax) base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);

        return ((ClassDeclarationSyntax) declaration).Update(
            declaration.Attributes,
            Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SealedKeyword)),
            declaration.Keyword,
            declaration.Identifier,
            declaration.TypeParameterListOpt,
            null,
            declaration.ConstraintClauses,
            declaration.OpenBraceToken,
            declaration.Members,
            declaration.CloseBraceToken,
            declaration.SemicolonTokenOpt);
    }

    protected override SyntaxNode VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var typeSyntax = node.Type;

        if (node.Identifier.ValueText == "Id")
        {
            typeSyntax = Syntax.IdentifierName("string");
        }

        var newProperty = Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(
            modifiers: Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)),
            type: typeSyntax,
            identifier: node.Identifier,
            accessorList: Syntax.AccessorList(
                accessors: Syntax.List(
                    Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration, 
                    semicolonTokenOpt: Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                    Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration,
                    semicolonTokenOpt: Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
                    )
                )
            );

        return newProperty;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to find a way to add the DataMember and DataContract custom attributes to MyClass but have been unsuccessful. How does one add the custom attributes?

Comment: The way I read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roslyn/thread/f5adeaf0-49d0-42dc-861b-0f6ffd731825) MSDN thread, I'd say that Roslyn doesn't support custom attributes. Have you seen something that indicates otherwise?

Comment: Roslyn does support attributes at the syntax level, just not the semantics

Comment: There is a AttributeDeclarationSyntax class and both the class and properties have an attributes member, but I cannot find an example how to construct it.  You can also rewrite attributes with a SyntaxRewiter. Here is an [example](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/10/20/in-bed-with-roslyn/) how to use it.  So I would think its supported, but I may be wrong.

Comment: SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(source) here ->SyntaxTree does not contains definition for "ParseCompilationUnit"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the parameters of the `Syntax.PropertyDeclaration` method is a list of attributes that apply to the attribute.  Like all `Syntax` elements, it is constructed using a factory method on the static `SyntaxFactory` class.

The [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) can be handy for figuring out how to generate syntax using Roslyn.

In your particular example, the `VisitPropertyDeclaration` method of your rewriter should look something like:

```
using static Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory;
...

    protected override SyntaxNode VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    var typeSyntax = node.Type;

    if (node.Identifier.ValueText == "Id")
    {
        typeSyntax = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("string");
    }

    var newProperty = PropertyDeclaration(
                PredefinedType(
                    Token(SyntaxKind.LongKeyword)),
                Identifier("Id"))
            .WithModifiers(
                TokenList(
                    Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
            .WithAccessorList(
                AccessorList(
                    List(new AccessorDeclarationSyntax[]{
                        AccessorDeclaration(
                            SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                        .WithSemicolonToken(
                            Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                        AccessorDeclaration(
                            SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration)
                        .WithSemicolonToken(
                            Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))})))
            .NormalizeWhitespace();

    return newProperty;
}
```

Comment: That I noticed, but I couldn't figure out how to initialize it, hence the question.

Comment: Can you please update you answer with the latest Roslyn syntax? 10x

Comment: This syntax doesn't look like it's supported anymore.  Any chance to see how it 's done now that they've sealed all the major classes?

Comment: Donvoted as this is now out-of-date information and needs updating.

Comment: Updated with latest syntax. You could have done this yourself easily using http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net