# Are there any visual studio template tools can generate source codes base on other source codes?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I have to write a lot of helper classes for some reasons like below:

```
//original class
public class Class1{
    public Class1(int p1,int p2){}
}
public class Class2{
    public Class2(int p3,int p4,int p5){}
}
//helper class
public static Helper{
    public static Class1(int p1,int p2){}
    public static Class2(int p3,int p4,int p5){}
}
```

I need auto generate these helpers at design time, so I think I need a tools require these feature:

- Template write at design time.
- Template varible can base on the exists classes in source codes at design time(means they are not compilered to Assembly).
- Can be auto generate when the source codes(classed) changed or then file saved.

Is there any tools like that?

BTW: Is there any tools can query classes at design time? like I want find classes that is not sealed when they dont have subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn).  I [rewrote classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204875/adding-custom-attributes-to-c-sharp-classes-using-roslyn) before using Roslyn, but only as an experiment, to inject attributes in the class. To make it work, I had to write a console application because Visual Studio 2010 didn't allow easy integration at the time.  Since the code didn't change much, it wasn't a problem to run manually.

You may be able to adapt it for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps (the T4 templates) ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx

Or there is a purely manual way to use the reflection
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19513/Dynamic-But-Fast-The-Tale-of-Three-Monkeys-A-Wolf

But I bet this is not the way you really want it.

Comment: I knew T4 template, but It may only get metadata after compilation.I'm looking for a template tool that can read metadata from source code at design time(like NDepend,can query class when you are coding at visual studio using CQL).If this kind of tools doesnt exists,maybe reflect from compiled assembly is the best way.