# Add [ApiController] Attribute to the class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, roslyn, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented the project of migrating Asp.Net WebApi into Asp.Net Core 3.1.I have started to learning the Rosyln parser. Using Rosyln, I have to change "ApiController" property into attribute in the class name.

**Sample.cs**

```
namespace TestFile.TestData.Target
{   
  public class SampleFile: ApiController
  {        
  }
}
```

into

```
namespace TestFile.TestData.Target
{   
  [ApiController]
  public class SampleFile: ControllerBase
  {        
  }
}
```

I have followed the link :
[Adding custom attributes to C# classes using Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204875/adding-custom-attributes-to-c-sharp-classes-using-roslyn). but didn't understand.

Kindly suggest on alternative solution on how to do using Roslyn.

Comment: What part did you not understand?

Comment: dont know how and where we do call the addattribute method calling and also SyntaxTree does not contains a definition of ParseCompilationUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this,

**Sample.cs**:

```
private void AddCustomClassAttribute(string TargetClassFile, string CustomAttributeName)
{    
    var code = File.ReadAllText(TargetClassFile);
    var updateClassFile = InsertClassAttribute(code, CustomAttributeName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(updateClassFile))
        File.WriteAllText(TargetClassFile, updateClassFile);           
}

private async Task<string> InsertClassAttribute(string Code, string CustomAttributeName)
{
    // Parse the code into a SyntaxTree.
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(Code);
    // Get the root CompilationUnitSyntax.
    var root = await tree.GetRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) as CompilationUnitSyntax;    
    var findNamespace = root.Members.Single(m => m is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax) as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax;
    // Get all class declarations inside the namespace.
    var classDeclarations = findNamespace.Members.Where(m => m is ClassDeclarationSyntax);
    // find the main class from the findNameSapce
    var findRootClass = classDeclarations.First() as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
    var addCustomAttribute = AttributeList(
                                SingletonSeparatedList(
                                    Attribute(IdentifierName(CustomAttributeName)))
                                ).NormalizeWhitespace();

    // To check whether specific attribute is present in the class or not then only insert given attribute
    if (findRootClass.BaseList?.Types.ToFullString().Trim() == CustomAttributeName)
    {
        var attributes = findRootClass.AttributeLists.Add(addCustomAttribute);
        root = root.ReplaceNode(
            findRootClass,
            findRootClass.WithAttributeLists(attributes)).NormalizeWhitespace();
        return root.ToFullString();
    }
    return null;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achvieve? You have successfully added `[ApiController]` there is no more extra steps. The link is about adding attribute via source generetor (code that writes code) if you are just trying to add attribute you don't need source generators.

Btw Roslyn is name of the c# compiler. Wich is used to creating your entire application, not a tool for adding attributes to a class :)

If you are trying to generate class via source generators maybe edit the question a little bit

Comment: okay, Then how to add custom Attribute in the class

Comment: Attribute is a class. To create custom attribute create class that inherits from Attribute also use suffix "Attribute" in its name (example public class MyNewCustomAttribute : Attribute). Applying is same as above just decorate class with it. Only weird think is that the Attribute suffix is not used so the attribute  is then added like so [MyNewCustom]